# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Page_ClientValidate' is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

My button click seems to generating this error on submission.....Dont understand quite why since i've used this exact button setup a few times already...

[image]

This is the original button code before click

```
asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Height="27px" Width="117px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.value = 'Please wait...'; if(Page_ClientValidate()) { this.disabled = true; } else {this.value = 'Submit'; return false;}" />
```

This is what happens to it after click

[image]

these are the files i'm referencing in the script

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="~/Styles/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated....don't quite know if i'm overlooking something

Answer (score 4):

the whole problem was that i didnt have any fields to valdidate. Once i plced required field validators the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

Looks like function Page_ClientValidate is not defined anywhere.

Define it and add validation code and it should be working.

```
function Page_ClientValidate() {
  // add validaion code and return true / false;
}
```

Comment: You think its because the form im currently creating doesnt consist of any required field validaotrs? Because i'm looking at previous uses of this button and Ive never had to create a function for this. I assumed it was in the jquery library.. Exuse me Because im fresh out of school and just git into the field if my response doesnt sound correct....i lack real world expereince..lol